# Problems with ajax_function i get an error

Tags: ajax

Hello stackowerflow people, ive got problem, im trying to use one of your community scripts, and i cant find out problem. I get error about this ajax_function, how can i solve it, or fix it please help, here is the script:

```
<script>
function editColumn(dbc)
{
    var params  = 'option=edit&dbc=' + dbc ;
    var Divdbc = 'edit_' + dbc;
    ajax_function('ajax_edit.php', params, Divdbc);
}
function saveColumn(dbc)
{
    var value = document.getElementById('date_'+dbc).value;
    var params     = 'option=save&value=' + value + '&Id' + dbc ;
    var Divdbc = 'edit_' + dbc;
    ajax_function('ajax_edit.php', params, Divdbc);
}
</script>
```

And here is the error which i get:

> ReferenceError: ajax_function is not defined

How can i possible create that ajax function to work with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that the ajax_function() is not declared or not found

find this keyword in any of your files "function ajax_function()"

or

check if it needs to import the script that contains function ajax_function()

example:

```html
<script src="thefile.js"></script>
```

Comment: How to make tahat ajax function, that it would work for my script?

Comment: What you have got was a custom ajax which only the original poster could provide...make one here which I recommend this standard 2015 web tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp then proceed here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp